# Optimal wager on two games given probability and odds

Tags: probability, expected-value

**Question.** Suppose I have two games I would like to wager \$100 dollars on, but that I'm not required to wager the full \$100, i.e. I can bet \$50 if I want.

The games: $A$ vs. $B$ and $C$ vs. $D$, where the probabilities of each team winning are

$$P(A) = \frac{7}{10},\quad P(B) = \frac{3}{10}\quad\quad\text{and}\quad\quad P(C)=\frac{1}{4},\quad P(D) = \frac{3}{4}.$$

I am quoted the following odds for each game:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{team} & \text{odds} \\ \hline
A & 2:7 \\ \hline
B & 3:1 \\ \hline
C & 7:2 \\ \hline
D & 1:3 \\ \hline
\end{array}.
$$

For example, if we bet on team $A$ we would need to wager \$7 to win \$2.

How should you bet?

---

**So far.** It seems to me that there may be several "right" answers, but many "wrong" answers. Initially, my idea was to just look at the individual expected payoffs:
$$
\mathbb{E}A = \frac{7}{10}(2) + \frac{3}{10}(-7) = \frac{-7}{10}\\
\mathbb{E}B = \frac{3}{10}(3) + \frac{7}{10}(-1) = \frac{1}{5} \\
\mathbb{E}C = \frac{1}{4}(7) + \frac{3}{4}(-2) = \frac{1}{4} \\
\mathbb{E}D = \frac{3}{4}(1) + \frac{1}{4}(-3) = 0$$

So we see that we should primarily wager on $B$ and $C$. As far as how much to allocate, I guess we could just scale the expected values of $B$ and $C$ such that we get
$$
\frac{1/5}{1/5 + 1/4} = \frac{4}{9}, \quad\quad \frac{1/4}{1/5 + 1/4} = \frac{5}{9}.
$$

So we wager about \$44 on $B$ and \$56 on $C$. Is this line of thinking correct, or is there actually an optimal wager that isn't what I have?

Comment: Why you don´t wage all money on C?

Comment: Optimal in what sense? If you want the maximum expected payoff, then it is optimal to wager it all on $C$. If you are very risk-averse, it may be optimal not to wager at all.

Comment: Makes sense. As you both mention, there are many "correct" ways to wager depending on your appetite for risk. However, wagering anything on $A$ could be deemed as "incorrect" since we are not given favorable odds in this sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the player is infinately risk averse she should bet $x$ on $C$ and $100-x$
on $D$ where $x$ is determined by the equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x}{2}\ast 7+x &=&\frac{100-x}{3}+100-x\rightarrow  \\
x &=&\frac{160}{7}
\end{eqnarray*}
Then, if $C$ wins she will get a net profit of $\frac{160}{7}\frac{7}{2}+%
\frac{160}{7}-100=2.8571.$

And if $D$ wins she will get a net profit of $\ \frac{100-\frac{160}{7}}{3}-(%
\frac{160}{7})=2.\,857\,1$

Hence, there is a possibility to make a guaranteed profit of $%
2.\,8571$ for every $100$ invested. It is thus a good strategy
if she had a credit card without limit.

Comment: This is great... I didn't see the arbitrage. Just to summarize for those who see this answer: The way that the odds are quoted, we can wager some amount on both $C$ winning and $D$ winning to guarantee a profit. One can try this for $A$ and $B$ and see that we do not have the same arbitrage opportunity (i.e. we can guarantee -2.7 loss).